# Camera don't show image in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using below code to access my laptop camera or usb webcam but it doesn't work. I am not sure how to debug this to get to root cause of this issue. Code and output:

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print (vid)
print (vid.isOpened())
while(vid.isOpened()):
     
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    print (ret)
    print (frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output of above is

```
<VideoCapture 0000000002DAE970>
True
False
None
```

When the **cv2.VideoCapture(0)** is executed I can see my laptop's camera light lit up and same happens when **cv2.VideoCapture(1)** is executed, I can see my webcam's light lit up. I am not sure why ret, frame = vid.read() ret is being return as False and image as None.

Please note that both cameras work in skype and other utilities. Even on VLC as well. I have checked in my device manager and they both show up. I am running this on Windows 7, openCV version is 4.5.5 and Python version is 3.8.6

Regards,
Yasar

Comment: What happens if you change the `if` to show the image if `ret` is true, and continue if false rather than breaking out of the `while` on the first failed read?

Comment: Hi @beaker - In this case it shows the window but it is grey with no image and below error is thrown which is expected as frame returned is none. And even if I continue the loop when frame is none it keeps printing the value of ret and frame which are always False and None. The exception thrown is: Exception is line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: `isOpened()` being **True** and yet the reads fail, that is curious! -- in some situations, `ret` can turn up True again even after being False before. it seems that is not the case here. -- please add to your question all available details on your cameras -- next you could try setting some properties on the cap objects, like width and height, frame rate, FOURCC (that one before everything else)